# Envio Json via GET do android

Tags: java, android

Problema nos caracteres especiais (*chaves, parenteses, etc*) que contem em um **json** que estou enviando via **GET**. O android gera o seguinte log:

```
> E/AndroidRuntime(1956): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal
> character in path at index 61:
> http://10.0.3.2:8084/meuapp/recurso/objeto/download/{}
```

Meu método **GET** é o seguinte

```
public static String GET(Context context, String endereco){
        //Verifica se existe conexão com a internet
        if(!existeConexao(context))
            return K.FALHA_CONEXAO;
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        String result = K.FALHA;
        try{
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(endereco);//A excessão acontece aqui
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
            if(inputStream!=null){
                //Converte resposta do WebService para String
                result = inputStreamParaString(inputStream);
            }else
                result = K.FALHA;
        }catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(ClientProtocolException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Porque não envia o objeto via `POST`? Não é comum enviar um objeto `JSON` pela url, apesar de ser possível. Se for realmente isso, porque não faz encoding da String antes de enviar?

Comment: Por POST funciona, mas eu queria seguir o padrão GET requisitar algo e POST alterar algo no servidor. Como posso fazer o encoding da String via GET?

Comment: Não cheguei a testar, mas acredito que o ` URLEncoder.encode("{}", "UTF-8");` deve resolver o problema.

Comment: Ok, mas {} é uma expressão gerada de um HashMap vazio (size==0), se o HashMap tivesse um tamanho maior será que esse encoding valeria?

Comment: Ah... Eu acho que você não pode usar o `HashMap` diretamente, porque ele não vai gerar `JSON`, o formato dele é `{chave=valor, chave=valor}`. Dê uma olhada no `JSONObject` e faça o encoding apenas no `toString` de uma instância dele e não na URL inteira.

Comment: Funcionou amigo, obrigado fiz da seguinte forma. 

json = URLEncoder.encode(json);
json = Sincronismo.GET(context, endereco + json);

Comment: Vou fazer mais alguns teste.

Comment: Quando finalizar, cria uma resposta com a solução. Pode ajudar outras pessoas quando visitarem a sua pergunta.

Comment: Pode responder voce que solucionou, o metodo que me disse funcionou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em geral as [`URI's`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) são definidas pelo RFC 3986 ([Seção 2 - Characters](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2)) e podem conter os seguintes caracteres:

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-._~:/?#[]@!$&'()*+,;=
```

Os demais precisam ser codificados no formato

```
%hh
```

E como o formato **JSON** possui o caractere **{** e **}**, que são inválidos, recomendo usar o método `URLEncoder.encode`:

```
JSONObject objetoJSON = new JSONObject();

// Popula seu json com as propriedades

String url = caminho.concat(URLEncoder.encode(objetoJSON.toString(), "UTF-8"));
```

E em vez de ter algo como:

```
http://10.0.3.2:8084/meuapp/recurso/objeto/download/{"chave1": "valor1", "chave2": "valor2"}
```

Terá algo como:

```
http://10.0.3.2:8084/meuapp/recurso/objeto/download/%7B%22chave1%22%3A%20%22valor1%22%2C%20%22chave2%22%3A%20%22valor2%22%7D
```

**Referências**

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547899/which-characters-make-a-url-invalid
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786042/java-url-encoding

Comment: Obrigado ficou dessa forma----------------------> json = URLEncoder.encode(json,"UTF-8"); 
resposta = Sincronismo.GET(context, endereco + json)